# Back to category link

Tags: categories

I've added the following code to my content.php which works great except the words '⟵ Back to' are a separate link to the 'category name' (news). I would like the hover to highlight the complete sentence as one item. EG:

⟵ Back to News

```
<a class"back-link" href="<?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">⟵ Back to <?php the_category ( ' ') ?></a>
```

Hello - I nearly works!! But I have two categories, 'news 'and 'members'. The link is correct but the category always says 'News' even when it should be 'Members'. Here's my code: `<a class"back-link" href="<?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">⟵ Back to <?php echo get_cat_name( $cat ); ?></a>`

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if this has worked for you. Good luck!

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Can you update your question? It will be easier than in the comments.

Comment: $cat[0] always gets the first category. If you have multiple categories, you should provide the full snippet of code. Or use $cat[1] where you need the second one.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. I just want a back to the parent category  link at the bottom of my single post view based on the category that the post is tagged with. So if a post is tagged 'news' the link will say '⟵ Back to News' and if the post is tagged 'member' the link will say  '⟵ Back to Members'. At the moment my code is in content.php. Is there are better way to do this?

Comment: try 'echo get_the_category();'

Comment: Sorry not @working Pim. Result is a single link but reads '⟵ Back to Array' : [

`<a class"back-link" href="<?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">⟵ Back to <?php echo get_the_category(); ?></a>`

Answer (score -1):

Use `echo get_cat_name( $cat );` instead of `the_category()` inside the link. `the_category()` returns a link, so you will have a link within a link.